# Not able to submit form - ReactJs, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to learn ReactJs and NodeJs and this is the first time I've been using them both. 
I have an app where backend is created with NodeJs and Express and frontend in ReactJs.

Server is working as it should, all endpoints are tested with Postman.
I'm trying to connect frontend with backend by creating new item.

It is simple CRUD app and it supposed to create, update and delete rooms in hotel.

I have a parent component `App.js` and two child component.
One child component is `Admin.js` where user can change room details and other child component is `LandingPage.js` where changes should be displayed.

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        initialTitle: '',
        initialDescription: '',
        initialPrice: ''
      }
    }

    onChangeTitle(newTitle) {
      this.setState({
        initialTitle: newTitle
      });
    }

    onChangeDescription(newDescription) {
      this.setState({
        initialDescription: newDescription
      });
    }

    onChangePrice(newPrice) {
      this.setState({
        initialPrice: newPrice
      });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const obj = {
        initialTitle: this.state.initialTitle,
        initialDescription: this.state.initialDescription,
        initialPrice: this.state.initialPrice
      };
      axios.post('http://localhost:27017/admin/add', obj)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

      this.setState({
        initialTitle: '',
        initialDescription: '',
        initialPrice: ''
      })
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <div>
            <Route path = "/" exact component = {LandingPage}/>
            <Route path = "/admin" component = {() =>
              <Admin 
              initialTitle = {
                this.state.initialTitle
              }
              initialDescription = {
                this.state.initialDescription
              }
              initialPrice = {
                this.state.initialPrice
              }
              changeTitle = {
                this.onChangeTitle.bind(this)
              }
              changeDescription = {
                this.onChangeDescription.bind(this)
              }
              changePrice = {
                this.onChangePrice.bind(this)
              }
              onSubmit = {
                this.onSubmit
              }
              />}/ >
```

**Admin.js**

I am using Boostrap 4 modal. When I click on button modal pops up and I should insert room details and click save button.

```
class Admin extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: props.initialTitle,
      description: props.initialDescription,
      price: props.initialPrice

    }
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log("save");
    this.props.changeTitle(this.state.title)
    this.props.changeDescription(this.state.description)
    this.props.changePrice(this.state.price)
  }


  onHandleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      title: event.target.value
    });
  }

  onHandleDescriptionChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      description: event.target.value
    });
  }

  onHandlePriceChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      price: event.target.value
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
          <div>  

      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createModal" class="btn btn-      primary btn-lg btn-block mb-5">Add new room</button>

          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="title" className="col-form-label">Title:</label>
                <input 
                type="text" 
                value={this.state.title} 
                onChange{(event)=>this.onHandleTitleChange(event)} 
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="message-text" className="col-form-label">Description:</label>
                <textarea 
                type="text" 
                value={this.state.description} 
                onChange{(event)=>this.onHandleDescriptionChange(event)}"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="title" className="col-form-label">Price:</label>
                <input 
                type="text" 
                value={this.state.price} 
                onChange={(event)=>this.onHandlePriceChange(event)} />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary"
            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button data-backdrop="false" type="button" 
            className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    )
  }

}
export default requireAuth(Admin);
```

When I hit save button nothing happens I don't get any error and my data is not saved in database.

**Backend code**

**room.route.js**

```
// Defined store route
roomRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
    let room = new Room(req.body);
    room.save()
      .then(room => {
        res.status(200).json({'room': 'room in added successfully'});
      })
      .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
      });
  });
```

**index.js**

```
//DB setup
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/hotel", { useNewUrlParser: true });

//App setup
app.use(morgan('combined')); //every incoming request is passed to morgan and bodyParser
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*'})); //morgan and bodyParser are like middleware in express

app.use('/admin', roomRoute);
router(app);

//Server setup
const port = process.env.PORT || 3090;
//create http server who knows how to recieve request and send to app
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
console.log('server listenining on ', port);
```

Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: The button "Save" should be inside the HTML Form tag and should be of type "submit"

Comment: If you hoist all your logic up to App level your app is going to be very quickly unmaintainable

Comment: @Dominic Okay, what would be a good solution for you? I thought this is a good one and also the way to pass data between child components using parent one.

Answer (score 0):

Within your function `onFormSubmit` into Admin component, you need to call your `onSubmit` prop as well.

```
onFormSubmit() {
    console.log("save");
    this.props.changeTitle(this.state.title)
    this.props.changeDescription(this.state.description)
    this.props.changePrice(this.state.price)
    this.props.onSubmit()
  }
```

Comment: I added it but same, nothing shows up :/ I forgot to mention that on server side and client side authentication is also set. So I log in as on of the users change room details and save it. Do you think this changes anything? I am really new to this

Comment: And also `console.log("save");` never gets displayed in console so function is never entered

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to call `App` component's `onSubmit` method  to make it work. You are passing it as a prop to `Admin` component but you are not using at all in `Admin` component.
In your `Admin` component's `onFormSubmit` method call `this.props.onSubmit` to send the call to `App` component's `onSubmit` method and then only it will  make the call to ur backend.

Change your onFormSubmit method to this:

```
onFormSubmit() {
    console.log("save");
    this.props.changeTitle(this.state.title)
    this.props.changeDescription(this.state.description)
    this.props.changePrice(this.state.price)
    this.props.onSubmit();
}
```

And yeah change your button type to `submit` inside your `Admin` component
Try that and let me know. Hope it helps!!

Comment: I soory but I am new to this and I don't quite understand how to do that can you please write in code?